# how can i extract elements from lists in python

Tags: python, list, element

I am trying to extract elements from list.
I've looked up a lot of data, but I do not know..

this is my test.txt (text file)
 [    left in the table = time,  right in the table = value   ]

```
0  81       
1  78       
2  76
3  74
4  81
5  79
6  80
7  81
8  83
9  83
10  83
11  82
  .
  .
22  81
23  80
```

If the current time is equal to the time in the table, i want to extract the value of that time.

this is my demo.py (python file)

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now())
current_hour = now.hour

with open('test.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

time = [int(line.split()[0]) for line in lines]
value = [int(line.split()[1]) for line in lines]

>>>time = [0,1,2,3,4,5,....,23]
>>>value = [81,78,76,......,80]
```

Comment: why don't you just use `value[current_hour]` since index/hour both start at 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a loop where you iterate over the list, looking for the current hour at every position on the list.

Starting at position 0, it will compare it with the current hour. If it's the same value, it will assign the value at the position it was found in "time" to the variable **`extractedValue`**, then it will *break* the loop.

If it isn't the same value, it will increase by 1 the **`pos`** variable, which we use to look into the list. So it will keep searching until the first **`if`** is True or the list ends.

```
pos=0
for i in time:
    if(current_hour==time[pos]):
        extractedValue=value[pos]
        break
    else:
        pos+=1
        pass
```

Feel free to ask if you don't understand something :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming unique values for the time column:

```
import datetime

with open('text.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

#this will create a dictionary with time value from test.txt as the key
time_data_dict = { l.split(' ')[0] : l.split(' ')[1] for l in lines }

current_hour = datetime.now().hour

print(time_data_dict[current_hour])
```

Comment: So, just so you can force this into a `dict` comprehension, youc all `l.split` twice each iteration of your loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
import csv
data = {}


with open('hour.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        k, v = row
        data[k] = v


hour = str(datetime.datetime.now().hour)

print(data[str(hour)])
```